# I have an RSS feed that I'm transforming with XSLT in order to display on my home page as HTML. The XML for the feed looks like this:

Tags: html, xml, xslt, rss

I have an RSS feed that I'm transforming with XSLT in order to display on my home page as HTML.  The XML for the feed looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="News.css" ?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
<title>Mutant Creations - News</title>
<link>http://www.mutantcreations.com</link>
<description>Don't worry, I'll distract the nerds.  Just get back to the ship!</description>

<item>
<title>Blog Pie</title>
<pubDate>Thursday, 26 Mar 2015 21:43:00 PT</pubDate>
<link>http://www.mutantcreations.com</link>
<description>Blog is up.</description>
<story>The Motion of Thought is Mr. Mutant's blog.  Check it out:<htext url="www.mutantcreations.com/Blog">Here</htext>.</story>
</item>

</channel> 
</rss>
```

And my XSL looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <h2>News!</h2>

       <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">

          <div style="color: #100000; padding:4px;">
             <span style="font-weight:bold;  text-decoration: underline;">
               <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
             </span>
          </div>

          <div style="color: #200000; padding:2px; font-size:11px;">
             <span>
               <xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/>
             </span>
          </div>

          <div style="margin: 1em 0 1em 2em; margin-right:25px;font-size:12pt;">
             <span>
               <xsl:value-of select="story"/>  
             </span>
          </div>
    </xsl:for-each>


   </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Using this same format, I'd like to take the contents of `<htext>` element and display it as an actual hyperlink inline with the rest of the `<story>` text.

```
<story>The Motion of Thought is Mr. Mutant's blog.  Check it out:<htext url="www.mutantcreations.com/Blog">Here</htext>.</story>
```

Furthermore, how can I do this for each `<htext>` element in every `<story>`?

Comment: `htext` is not hyperlink. Do you want an actual hyperlink or the code you have posted?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `<xsl:value-of select="story" />` use `xsl:apply-templates`

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="story"/>
```

XSLT's built-in templates can be used to match `story` (so the `story` element won't appear in the output itself) so you only need a template that matches `htext` to transform it.

```
<xsl:template match="htext">
    <a href="{@url}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <h2>News!</h2>
       <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
          <div style="color: #100000; padding:4px;">
             <span style="font-weight:bold;  text-decoration: underline;">
               <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
             </span>
          </div>
          <div style="color: #200000; padding:2px; font-size:11px;">
             <span>
               <xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/>
             </span>
          </div>
          <div style="margin: 1em 0 1em 2em; margin-right:25px;font-size:12pt;">
             <span>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="story"/>  
             </span>
          </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="htext">
    <a href="{@url}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </a>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input sample, the following is output

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>News!</h2>
      <div style="color: #100000; padding:4px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;  text-decoration: underline;">Blog Pie</span></div>
      <div style="color: #200000; padding:2px; font-size:11px;"><span>Thursday, 26 Mar 2015 21:43:00 PT</span></div>
      <div style="margin: 1em 0 1em 2em; margin-right:25px;font-size:12pt;"><span>The Motion of Thought is Mr. Mutant's blog.  Check it out:<a href="www.mutantcreations.com/Blog">Here</a>.</span></div>
   </body>
</html>
```